# Issues with creating column name for DataFrame in Python3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I do not understand why "u" has NaNvalues. What wrong am I doing here?

```
>>> z=pd.DataFrame([['abcb','asasa'],['sdsd','aeio']])
>>> z
          0      1
    0  abcb  asasa
    1  sdsd   aeio
>>> u=pd.DataFrame(z,columns=['hello','ajsajs'])
>>> u
    hello  ajsajs
 0    NaN     NaN
 1    NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Alternate construction calls

You can use the underlying NumPy array:

```
u = pd.DataFrame(z.values, columns=['hello','ajsajs'])

  hello ajsajs
0  abcb  asasa
1  sdsd   aeio
```

Alternately, you could use:

```
u = z.rename(columns={0: 'hello',1: 'ajsajs'})
```

And lastly as suggested by @Dark:

```
u = z.set_axis(['hello','ajsajs'], axis=1, inplace=False)
```

A small note on `inplace` in `set_axis` -

> WARNING: `inplace=None` currently falls back to to `True`, but in a future
>   version, will default to `False`. Use `inplace=True` explicitly rather
>   than relying on the default.

In pandas 0.20.3 the syntax would be just:

```
u = z.set_axis(axis=1, labels=['hello','ajsajs'])
```

@Dark's solution appears fastest here.

#### Why current method doesn't work

I believe the issue here is that there's a `.reindex` being called when the DataFrame is constructed in this way.  Here's some source code where ellipses denote irrelevant stuff I'm leaving out:

```
from pandas.core.internals import BlockManager

# pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
class DataFrame(NDFrame):
    def __init__(self, data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None,
                 copy=False):
        # ...
        if isinstance(data, DataFrame):
            data = data._data
        if isinstance(data, BlockManager):
            mgr = self._init_mgr(data, axes=dict(index=index, columns=columns),
                                 dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
        # ... a bunch of other if statements irrelevant to your case
        NDFrame.__init__(self, mgr, fastpath=True)
        # ...
```

What's happening here:

- DataFrame inherits from a more generic base class which in turn has multiple inheritance.  (Pandas is great, but its source can be like trying to backtrack through a spider's web.)
- In `u = pd.DataFrame(z,columns=['hello','ajsajs'])`, `x` is a DataFrame.  Therefore, the first `if` statement below is True and `data = data._data`.  What's `_data`?  It's a [`BlockManager`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-design/blob/master/source/internal-architecture.rst#removal-of-blockmanager--new-dataframe-internals).*  (To be continued below...)
- Because we just converted what you passed to its BlockManager, the next `if` statement also evaluates True.  Then `mgr` gets assigned to the result of the `_init_mrg` method and the parent class's `__init__` gets called, passing `mgr`.

* confirm with `isinstance(z._data, BlockManager)`.

Now on to part 2...

```
# pandas.core.generic.NDFrame
class NDFrame(PandasObject, SelectionMixin):
    def __init__(self, data, axes=None, copy=False, dtype=None,
             fastpath=False):
    # ...

    def _init_mgr(self, mgr, axes=None, dtype=None, copy=False):
        """ passed a manager and a axes dict """
        for a, axe in axes.items():
            if axe is not None:
                mgr = mgr.reindex_axis(axe,
                                       axis=self._get_block_manager_axis(a),
                                       copy=False)
    # ...
        return mgr
```

Here is where `_init_mgr` is defined, which gets called above.  Essentially in your case you have:

```
columns=['hello','ajsajs']
axes=dict(index=None, columns=columns)
# ...
```

**When you go to reindex axis and specify a new axis where none of the new labels are included in the old object, you get all NaNs.**  This seems like a deliberate design decision.  Consider this related example to prove the point, where one new column is present and one is not:

```
pd.DataFrame(z, columns=[0, 'ajsajs'])

      0  ajsajs
0  abcb     NaN
1  sdsd     NaN
```

Comment: You can also add `u = z.set_axis(['hello','ajsajs'],1,inplace=False)`

Comment: @Dark, really nice option. For the sake of completness we could also add: `z.columns = ['hello','ajsajs']`